# install google-chrome isnt working, why?

Tags: google-chrome, launcher, google

I am currently using ubuntu 16.04
The weird thing is, I have installed google chrome in my laptop using ubuntu 14.04 and worked perfectly.

Somehow I just installed ubuntu 16.04 into my desktop and trying to install chrome but just wouldn't work.

I went to the google chrome website and clicked download, I have the 64bit deb file, clicked on it and my software GUI popped up.  I click on install but it just keep on stalling, stays there forever and wouldn't move.

As I remember installing chrome in my laptop, after clicking install the process bar appears and bar will move but somehow now when I click install, it just keeps on showing install.  I checked my launcher bar to the left, there's something new but only says waiting to install.  It stays there for at least 2 hours and nothing happens.

Can someone give me a hand on what is going on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, it's a known bug. Should be fixed in later updates. For now, install deb files with the GDebi app

Comment: The easiest way is to install a deb with `sudo dpkg -i`. If the dependencies are not installed, run `sudo apt install -f` after that.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju is that bug for ubuntu 16.04? Because I just recently installed 16.04 into my pc but about 1-2mths ago I installed 14.04 into my laptop and my laptop installed chrome perfectly and I am new at ubuntu system so thought I did something wrong instead of having a bug

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks I took a look at the link, I believe that's what I need and will try that later when I get home.  Thanks thanks

Comment: @BharadwajRaju just realized, this doesn't just happen to google though.  I tried installing sublime text and same thing happened.

Comment: Yes. 16.04 made the switch to GNOME Software instead of Ubuntu Software Center, and GNOME Software had a bug that doesn't allow install of third-party `.deb`s. The fix is to be released later.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju ah ha, alright.  At first I thought the unknown bug was just for chrome not the whole thing :D thanks thanks

Comment: @Dora: You can install `.deb`s by using gdebi or synaptic. Open a Termional window and type: `sudo apt-get install gdebi`. You can install synaptic in the same manner, just replace gdebi for synaptic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fail-proof method of installing Chromium (open-source version of Chrome) would be to open a Terminal window and type:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Alternatively, installing Chrome from Terminal window is like this:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb  
sudo dpkg -i ./google-chrome*.deb  
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: This is wrong. Did you ever try to run this command?

Comment: @Pilot6: Sorry about that. My bad. I was thinking Chromium instead of Chrome.

Comment: This command will not install neither Chrome, nor Chromium.

Comment: Now it looks much better.